# Unable to run python web application in browser

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, web-applications, tkinter, pyjamas

we have created the python desktop application using Tkinter library and it is working. we converted the desktop app into web app using pyjamas and it generated the html files & javascripts.

While opening the html file in the browser, it showing the following error in the message box,

```
"WebGUI ImportError: No module named Tkinter.*, Tkinter.* in context None"
```

Is anything needs to be configured or setup to run this in web ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: use web framework like `Flask` or `Django` and create it from scratch - web applications work different then desktop applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyjamas doesn't support translating a tkinter app, and you definitely can't run a tkinter app in a web browser.